# How to see Word document text changes in ThisDocument_New()

Tags: debugging, ms-word, vsto

I'm considering migration of all of our Word templates from VBA to VSTO and have the following question: How can I debug code in a VSTO project?

Unlike debugging in VBA, I can't see the results of code executing line-by-line when stepping through a procedure.

For example, I build a prototype Word document in VS 2019:

```
using ...;
namespace MyCompany.OfficeTemplates.MyTemplate
    {
        public partial class ThisDocument
        {

            private void ThisDocument_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
            }

            private void ThisDocument_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
            }

            private void ThisDocument_New()
            {
                var currentSelection = Application.Selection;
                currentSelection.TypeText("This text was added by using code.");
            }

            #region VSTO Designer generated code

            /// ...<summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InternalStartup()
            {
                this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisDocument_Startup);
                this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisDocument_Shutdown);
                this.New += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentEvents2_NewEventHandler(this.ThisDocument_New);
            }

            #endregion

        }
    }
```

I plan to put way more code (showing a dialog box, choosing customers, choosing language and other information) into the `ThisDocument_New()` event. Why is the text not inserted into the word document when I step over the command ...TypeText()... with the debugger?!?

Instead, It's inserted when debugger leaves `ThisDocument_New()`?

What am I missing and where else to put my code when ThisDocument_New() does not allow propper debugging?

Answer (score 0):

That one cannot see what's happening during code execution is typical for VSTO. Debugging is different than with VBA - the results are only visible *after the code has finished*. Nothing can be done to change this - it's in the nature of the thing (.NET <-> COM interaction).

I struggled with this, myself, when starting with VSTO, and had to learn to work around it.

Generally, if during trouble-shooting it's necessary to see what's happening as it happens, I first test in VBA, then transfer that code to VSTO.

If it's necessary to check values being generated by code as it runs I stick some `Debug.Print` lines in that I can follow in the Visual Studio output window when stepping through the code.

It's also possible to track what's assigned to objects when stepping through the code.

Comment: Thanks Cindy for your reply, what is the motivation then to switch from VBA to VSTO if you have to test the code first in VBA and then move it to VSTO ?

Comment: One does not HAVE to test the code first in VBA - it's sometimes just simpler to trouble-shoot "odd" situations or to work out proof-of-concept. I do a lot of work in C# without migrating from VBA. Some reasons that come immediately to mind for choosing VBA vs. VSTO: 1) Distribution/maintenance of a project; 2) Use of capabilities that aren't available in the one or the other; 3) Security considerations